# Idiom for as flat as

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, comparatives

Could someone please show me any word or phrase that could fit with

> as flat as _______

. Grammar is important.

Comment: The idiom is usually as [flat as a pancake](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-as-flat-as-a-pancake) - it's a simple google away?

Comment: Context is important, too. What are you qualifying as flat? There are set idioms that have been provided here, but also more creative expressions.

Answer (score 1):

***[(as) flat as a pancake](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flat-as-a-pancake)*** is the more common idiomatic expression. ***Flat as a flounder***  is a [less common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flat%20as%20a%20pancake%2Cflat%20as%20a%20flounder&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflat%20as%20a%20pancake%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflat%20as%20a%20flounder%3B%2Cc0) alternative:

> Extremely level, especially too much so. For example, *There are no hills; this terrain is flat as a pancake*.
>
> This simile dates from the 1500s and has survived its contemporary, flat as a flounder. *It is sometimes used, either disparagingly or ruefully, to describe a small-breasted woman.*

(AHD)

Comment: The pejorative description of either gender is **pirate's** (sunken) chest